# DatePicker inside Select - prevent select to close on date change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a DatePicker inside Select - 
In antd how to prevent Select box to close on choosing date in datepicker:
https://codesandbox.io/s/0y1150wrvl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you'll get your solution with using manually `open` and `onOpenChange`.
It's little tricky but perfect.

https://codesandbox.io/s/104m845llj

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onSelect` event and `open` state to control the state of your select component.

Docs: https://ant.design/components/select/#API